# Java Tab Pane insert another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im new to Java GUI and I just want to ask how to put another class in a tab pane using eclipse.

Here is my code:

```
package tabexperiment;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory; 
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;


public class Gamemulator extends JPanel {
    public Gamemulator() {

        super(new GridLayout(1,0));


        Border blackline, raisedetched, loweredetched,
               raisedbevel, loweredbevel, empty;

        Border paneEdge = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,100,100,100);

        blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);


        JPanel base = new JPanel();
        base.setBorder(paneEdge);
        base.setLayout(new BoxLayout(base,
                                              BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        addCompForBorder(blackline, "Game Emulator",
                         base);




        //Second pane: TicTacToe
        JPanel tictactoe = new JPanel();

        tictactoe.setBorder(paneEdge);
        tictactoe.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tictactoe,
                                              BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Main", null, base, null);
        tabbedPane.addTab("TicTac", null, tictactoe, null);
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);     
        add(tabbedPane);


    }



    void addCompForTitledBorder(TitledBorder border,
                                String description,
                                int justification,
                                int position,
                                Container container) {
        border.setTitleJustification(justification);
        border.setTitlePosition(position);
        addCompForBorder(border, description,
                         container);
    }

    void addCompForBorder(Border border,
                          String description,
                          Container container) {
        JPanel comp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1), false);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(description, JLabel.CENTER);
        comp.add(label);
        comp.setBorder(border);

        container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        container.add(comp);
    }



    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gamemulator version 1.0");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        Gamemulator newContentPane = new Gamemulator();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                createAndShowGUI();
            }


        });
    }
}
```

I would like to put my TicTacToe class inside the second tab pane. How can I do this?
Also how can I add text after my first border text at the first tab?

Here's the tictactoe code:

```
package tabexperiment;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TicTac extends JApplet {
  private char whoseTurn = 'X';
  private Cell[][] cells =  new Cell[3][3];

  private JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel("X's turn to play");

  public TicTac() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        p.add(cells[i][j] = new Cell());

    p.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1));
    jlblStatus.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.yellow, 1));

    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

  public boolean isFull() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        if (cells[i][j].getToken() == ' ')
          return false;

    return true;
  }

  public boolean isWon(char token) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      if ((cells[i][0].getToken() == token)
          && (cells[i][1].getToken() == token)
          && (cells[i][2].getToken() == token)) {
        return true;
      }

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      if ((cells[0][j].getToken() ==  token)
          && (cells[1][j].getToken() == token)
          && (cells[2][j].getToken() == token)) {
        return true;
      }

    if ((cells[0][0].getToken() == token)
        && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
        && (cells[2][2].getToken() == token)) {
      return true;
    }

    if ((cells[0][2].getToken() == token)
        && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
        && (cells[2][0].getToken() == token)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  public class Cell extends JPanel {
    private char token = ' ';

    public Cell() {
      setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1)); 
      addMouseListener(new MouseListener()); 
    }

    /** Return token */
    public char getToken() {
      return token;
    }

    /** Set a new token */
    public void setToken(char c) {
      token = c;
      repaint();
    }

    /** Paint the cell */
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      if (token == 'X') {
        g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
        g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10, 10, 10, getHeight() - 10);
      }
      else if (token == 'O') {
        g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
      }
    }

    private class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
      /** Handle mouse click on a cell */
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ') {
          setToken(whoseTurn); 

          if (isWon(whoseTurn)) {
            jlblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + " won! The game is over");
            whoseTurn = ' '; 
          }
          else if (isFull()) {
            jlblStatus.setText("Draw! The game is over");
            whoseTurn = ' ';
          }
          else {
            whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? 'O': 'X'; 
            jlblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + "'s turn"); 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /** This main method enables the applet to run as an application */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe");

    TicTac applet = new TicTac();

    frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your TicTac class shouldn't extend from JApplet if you intend to add it to other containes. Instead, extend from something like JPanel, this gives you the freedoms to add it to what ever container you want...

Comment: Let say I changed the JApplet into JPanel, how could I connect it to my 2nd Tab? Any procedure? and I just noticed changing the JApplet change the size of my tictactoe.

Comment: You just have to `add` the TicTac panel to whereever you want. You can add it inside the `tictactoe` panel you created or directly put it in the `JTabbedPane`.  `TicTac tictactoe = new TicTac();`  `tabbedPane.addTab("TicTac", null, tictactoe, null);`